# Why does there seem to be a length on my pgrep pattern?

Tags: bash, grep

I couldn't for the life of me figure out why `pgrep` wasn't returning the PID of my process.  Then, in a last futile attempt, I just typed part of the executable's name, and voilá, there was the PID.  Which led to this experiment:

```
bash-4.1$ ./test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67890.sh &
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67890
me 16695 21716  0 06:04 /root/dev/pts/2 00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67890.sh
me 16945 22027  0 06:04 /root/dev/pts/3 00:00:00 grep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67890
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67890
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_6789
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_678
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_67
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_6
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz_
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxyz
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwxy
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vwx
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_vw
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_v
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345_
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12345
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_1234
16695
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_123
16695
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_12
16695
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_1
16695
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde_
16695
bash-4.1$ pgrep test_abcde
16695
```

I couldn't find this behavior documented in the man page.  Is this normal?  Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man page on my system includes this note:

> The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters present in the output of /proc/pid/stat.  Use the -f option to match against the complete command line, /proc/pid/cmdline.

Comment: A-ha. The man page on my system includes this note as well, but I missed it.